# Why does strtotime("a potato") gives the current time minus 1 hour?

Tags: php, strtotime

PHP strtotime() acts abnormal when it comes to "a potato". Why is that?

Comment: What is your [default time zone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php)?

Comment: Produces the exact same timestamp as `time()` for me ~ https://3v4l.org/SWgg9

Comment: @Phil want to see more weird stuff? https://3v4l.org/RIGre

Comment: @Sammitch yeah, it seems (almost) any string matching `/[a-zA-Z] *[a-zA-Z]{,6}/` produces a current timestamp.

Comment: @Phil Yes, but look at DateTime's behaviour, specifically the UTC offsets. Also fun bits at indices `gb` and `nz`, but nothing else.

Comment: `echo strtotime("a potato", (int) "in the oven");`

Comment: I guess it's interpreting those as [military time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_time_zones), hence why `J` is skipped.

Comment: Anyway OP, this is a great opportunity to realize that "`strtotime()` and similar functions just make _educated guesses_ about how to parse date strings, and those guesses can be _wildly inaccurate_". Use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat).